# Select the latest MySQL Data but unique resort

Tags: php, mysql, sql, resultset

I have a 1 table database that has a list of advertisements.
I am trying to grab the **LATEST advertisement** for **EACH resort**. 
I know it should probably be a table database, but how would I go about doing so.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t.*
from YourTable t
join
    (select resort, max(dateAdded) dateAdded
    from YourTable
    group by resort) m on t.dateAdded = m.dateAdded and t.resort = m.resort
order by t.resort
```

First group the rows by resort to find the max of dateAdded, then query (join) the rows that have the same dateAdded with the max.

One problem is, if the same resort **b** is added in the same time, twice or more, it will take only the first row. But I think is slightly possible.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the Id column is unique:

```
SELECT T3.*
FROM yourtable AS T3
JOIN
(
    SELECT T2.resort, T2.date_added, MAX(T2.id) AS id
    FROM yourtable AS T2
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT resort, MAX(date_added) AS date_added
        FROM yourtable
        GROUP BY resort
    ) AS T1
    ON T1.resort = T2.resort AND T1.date_added = T2.date_added
    GROUP BY T2.resort, T2.date_added
) AS T4
ON T4.id = T3.id
```

Comment: Downvoter: Could you please tell me what is wrong instead of just downvoting? I'd be happy to correct the error.

Comment: I'm curious too, you even look at the entries added in the same time..  which makes your answer the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) function

```
SELECT MAX(dateAdded), resort, linkToUrl FROM `your_table` GROUP BY resort
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
SELECT * FROM advertisements GROUP BY resort ORDER BY dateAdded DESC
```